# synchronizing layers in parallax scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, vertical-scrolling, android-adapterview, onfling

I need to implement a scrolling layout which is loaded with images from an `Adapter`, and another scrolling layout on top of it (second layer of a `FrameLayout`) that contains text labels of individual images. The top layer should scroll with a "parallax effect": http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Parallax_scrolling_example_scene.gif -- but in our case, unlike in that animation, the items in the background and foreground layers are related to each other since the text labels obviously belong to and describe the images. The layers can be [listviews with custom dynamics](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/06/23/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-3/) (top one is faster than the bottom one) but I'm not sure how to sync them; couple of ideas:

- when movement stops in both layers, redraw one of them to match the visible items of the other list -- but this leads to flicker/jumps
- or top layer could dynamically increase spacing between the items based on velocity so the slower background layer could keep up with its movement -- but I'm not sure of the Math required for this

Comment: Maybe something like that would help you out ( I found it in another thread):                                               `<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/contents"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/child_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

 <ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/bgr"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:background="@drawable/some_image">

  </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>`

Comment: in which way would this help? ... seems like completely unrelated to my question

Comment: This is the basic layout setup for the paralax movement. I think that it can serve you well for the base of your implementation if I understood it well. It's not a complete solution and that's why I posted it in a comment. I don't know how to implement the rest of your requirement, but the one I've given works well. If it's not related to what you want, I would gladly delete the comment.

Comment: Look at this lib: https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView look it's done and adapt to your needs.

Comment: @mikooos, he did not implement sync between items of two listview-style layers which my question is about

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Parallax effect requires two layers to move at different speeds (tree #1 is initially drawn in front of mountain #1 but later (as user continues to scroll) in front of mountain #2) but related items require the same speed (text #1 should always appear in front of image #1). So of course it flickers when you bring them back in sync again.

Comment: @devconsole, they should sync after the user made a fling gesture -- so it's different than in the demo where there is infinite scrolling. One idea I had is to increase the spacing of list items in the top layer so as to make up for its faster velocity, but I was not sure how to calculate the exact spacing based on fling dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally implemented it using a fast scrolling top layer with bigger size albums and two slower bottom layers with small albums (both layers have text and image combined together).

Comment: there is a follow-up with code: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62723/trouble-with-a-modified-parallax-scrolling-concept

Answer (score 0):

Use the 2 listviews with custom dynamics and then relate their speed by the distance between the images. So, where x is the speed of the foreground listview and y is the speed of the background listview, y=x*(subimage2.y-subimage1.y)*percentile.

Comment: hi @steven-mann, the speed is dependent on the fling gesture the user provides, so it's the spacing that should be changed by our algorithm. By the way, the foreground has only text labels and the background has the images of various sizes that they describe.

Comment: x would be the raw fling input, and you would calculate the image distance based on far apart the background images are (which should be static, so you could technically precalculate). The y output will be the positioning of your background view. Regarding the percentile, that is a necessary speed modifier constant. I would start with 0.01 and then modify as you wish.

Comment: hi @steven-mann, guess you answered my comment before I edited it... not sure you got my problem so pls look at my edit. So the fling gesture applies simultaneously to both layers but because the foreground is faster, it should have increased spacing (and the question is how much that should be based on fling velocity).